# Google tasks api sample code not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've installed the sample code for google tasks python api and for some reason, everytime I visit localhost:8000, I get redirected to:

```
localhost:8000/instances
```

I don't understand what I could have done wrong - it was a straight copy and paste of the sample code.

Please help me debug this,

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was loading the wrong port number (8000 instead of 8080)